# Swift package manager: artifact of binary target failed download: invalid status code 404

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

I have created a Swift package manager using a private repo. The xcframework zip file is located in this private repo. The swift package manager set up is sitting in a public repo. When I try to integrate this SPM ( swift package manager ) in a sample app, I see below error. Please can anyone suggest what can i do to fix this.

[image]

What I have already tried :

I tried to use a SSH authentication instead of https in Xcode preferences accounts, when I do that it fails on first step itself while cloning the public SPM repo.

Error :
[image]

Comment: I managed to fix this by adding the ssh key to my GitHub account which allowed to access the private repos without any issues.

Comment: Can we use that with binaryTarget? (I tried unsuccessfully)

Answer (score 3):

A proper solution to this issue is coming in [Swift release 5.4](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-5-4-release-process/41936)
The solution is similar to that used in Carthage with a NetRC file. This [pull request](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/pull/2833) details how the solution works in Swift 5.4

Comment: Is there a way to test this now ? So that i can mark this as an answer